# In my react code :- speechSynthesis property utterance.rate is giving so much difficulties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, speech

I'm making a survey page and wanted to add voice to my Survey Question and its options and I used the web speech API speechSynthesis. yes it worked in my code but when I used a property of ( speechSynthesis ) utterance.rate . It's not giving me proper result when I gived value less than 1 (ex=>  utterance.rate = 0.4;)  it is crashing my whole function and stop working .

```
onClick={(value) => audioPlay(surveyQues[quesNo].question, surveyQues[quesNo].options)}

const audioPlay = (question, option) => {
      
        let text = question

        option.forEach((option, index) => {
            text = `${text} ${'\xa0'} option ${index + 1} ${option.option}`
        })
        let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
        utterance.rate = 0.4;
        utterance.pitch = 0.8;
        synth.speak(utterance);

        console.log(utterance)
    };
```